# Why is UIActivityViewController displaying auto constraint errors in console

Tags: swift, ios13, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to implement the Share functionality using UIActivityViewController. Using Swift 5, Xcode 11.2.1, ios 13.2.

I have used UITableViewController and in the rows's click I have called the share() method as shown below :

```
class SettingsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var tableData = ["Share with friends"]

    // MARK: - Table view methods
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "settingsCell", for: indexPath)
        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        share()
    }

    func share() {
        print("Share with friends")
        let items: [Any] = ["This app is my favorite", URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!]
        let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
        self.present(ac, animated: true)

    }
}
```

I get the below error on clicking of the 'Share with friends' row. The strange thing is that the error doesn't occur always.

```
2019-11-18 14:28:23.951523+0530 ShareSheetDemo[425:18210] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282b740f0 _UIActivityActionCellTitleLabel:0x11fd94510.height >= 22   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282b692c0 V:|-(15)-[_UIActivityActionCellTitleLabel:0x11fd94510]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x11fd92fb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282b69540 V:[_UIActivityActionCellTitleLabel:0x11fd94510]-(15)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x11fd92fb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282b74280 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x11fd92fb0.height == 50.5   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282b740f0 _UIActivityActionCellTitleLabel:0x11fd94510.height >= 22   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2019-11-18 14:28:25.925309+0530 ShareSheetDemo[425:18241] [ShareSheet] connection invalidated
```

I see that the error was there in iOS 9 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954171/why-is-activityviewcontroller-displaying-auto-constraint-errors-in-console) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623893/uiactivityviewcontroller-unable-to-simultaneously-satisfy-constraints-on-devic). I cannot comment on these issues itself asking if they have been solved because I don't have the required reputation. 
As mentioned in these issues -

1. I have used a UITableViewController in the Storyboard, so I have not manually added any constraints.
2. I tried using the sourceRect mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623893/uiactivityviewcontroller-unable-to-simultaneously-satisfy-constraints-on-devic), but to no avail.

Also, I got the error when I ran the app on an actual device. The simulator does not give the error.

Could someone help me fix this error? Or is this issue known and is not fixed? Thanks.!

Comment: I am getting the same errors in console whenever I try to present share sheet... Seems like it's iOS error.

Comment: FWIW I am also seeing the same error. I haven't found any workaround yet.

Answer (score 10):

This is Apple’s bug, not yours. Ignore the console message and move on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work with you, but one of the other engineers on our team found that the wrapping the `present(_:animated:)` call in a dispatch block seems to resolve the issue (at least in our app).

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.present(controller, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Worked only partially for me. Less error messages but still some. I will just ignore them.